# React js test boolean prop with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

New to testing, so not I'm sure how to approach this. I have a bool `prop` in my component that determines the `className` of an element. The Boolean is set whether the form is valid or not showing the `div` containing an error message

```
<div>
   <div className={!this.props.isValid ? 'login__error error' : 'hidden'}>
      ...
   </div>
</div>
```

How to test this in Jest?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
Following the answer by @hemerson-carlin here's my test. But keeps failing  with `RangeError: Invalid string length` not sure why.

```
describe('Given invalid details the form should display an error', () => {
  let component

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = mount(<Login />)
  })

  it('should render valid mode', () => {
    component.setProps({ isValid: true })
    console.log(component.props())

    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  it('should render invalid mode', () => {
    component.setProps({ isValid: false })
    console.log(component.props())

    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

})
```

Comment: Please add you jest code too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way at the end, simpler than I thought.

```
test('Given invalid details the form should display an error', () => {

  const login = mount(<Login isValid={false}/>);
  expect(login.find('.error').hasClass('login__error')).toBeTruthy();

})

test('Given valid details the form should not display an error', () => {

  const login = mount(<Login isValid={true}/>);
  expect(login.find('.error').hasClass('hidden')).toBeTruthy();

})
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use snapshot testing for both cases:

```
describe('YourComponent test', () => {
  let component

  beforeEach(() => {
    component = mount(<YourComponent />)
  })

  it('should render valid mode', () => {
    component.setProps({ isValid: true })
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
  })

  it('should render invalid mode', () => {
    component.setProps({ isValid: false })
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply and help, but test (with both approaches) keeps failing unfortunately  ```expect(object).toHaveProperty(path, value)
    
    Expected the object:
      {"isValid": false}
    To have a nested property:
      "className"
    With a value of:
      "login__error error"
```

Comment: The second approach is not recommended (that's why I wrote `Something like`). In the first case, can you log `component.props()`?

Comment: `component` seems to be undefined. Are you sure this is not a typo? Are you importing `mount` from enzyme?

Comment: Managed to log the props but... ```● Console

    console.log __tests__/base/components/Login.test.js:35
      { isValid: true }
    console.log __tests__/base/components/Login.test.js:42
      { isValid: false }

  ● Given invalid details the form should display an error › should render valid mode

    RangeError: Invalid string length
```

Comment: `className` isn't part of your component props. That's why you tests fail.

Comment: yes I know, how can `className` be my component prop if it's React reserved? I'm confused

Comment: Component props are all props you need to render your component (such as `isValid`). `className` on the other hand is an _attribute_.

Comment: So is there a way to test what is the `className` value according to `isValid`?

Comment: Why do you need to check the `className`? I suggest you to read about `snapshot tests` instead :)